# Django model: creating small value fixed point

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

**Summary**

I'm building a project in Django - and will many small-range positive decimal values (`1.25`, `0.01`, etc). In the database (MySQL), it makes sense to store them as `value*10^precision`. This means instead of storing a `float` type (4 bytes), I can get away with a `SmallInt`(2 bytes). This is rad when it's megabytes of data.

**Problem**
The issue is when Django and the `PositiveSmallIntegerField()` makes a widget that automatically checks for "whole number" values!

*Option 1:* Use a DecimalField() in the model code, and whenever the database changes, I update the SQL to be a SMALLINT(3).

```
PRECISION=2

class MyModule(models.Model):

    ...<fields>

    def readySave(self):
        pseudoDecimalField *= 10**PRECISION

    def setValues(self):
        pseudoDecimalField /= 10**PRECISION

    def save(self): 
        # pre-save things here
        self.readySave()
        super(MyModule, self).save()
        # post-save things here
        self.setValues()
```

*Option 2:* Use raw SQL commands when pushing/pulling values.

Any opinions or experiences on the matter are much appreciated. Does anyone have any other ways to make this happen?

Comment: What about creating your own field?

Comment: I think your optimizing needlessly. I think you should just store it as float and be done with it

Comment: Also, you can override the widget of the model (I assume you are using a model form) to anything else, like say widget = DecimalField

Comment: @JamesR you're right - it probably is premature optimization, unless he's going to have hundreds of millions of rows, the space savings are just not significant.

Comment: @JamesR I suppose premature optimization /is/ the devil. Didn't see the widget overwriting in the docs, but there it is. Thanks for the words!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is only in "frontend" part, so there must be a way to solve the problem without modifying database. The neatest way to do that is to overwrite widget for the field in form. It should look like that:

```
class MyModuleForm(forms.Form):
    ....
    pseudoDecimalField = forms.PositiveSmallIntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput)
```

You can read more about widgets in great Django [documentatin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/).